# JSONPath extracting values

Tags: scala, jsonpath

I want extract all the offerId's from just one of the membershipId's below:

```
{
   "resultCode": "SUCCESS",
   "errorCode": null,
   "errorMessage": null,
   "membershipCoupons":
   [
       {
           "membershipId": "32021428",
           "coupons":
           [
               {
                   "offerId": "000C291EE8241ED4AAF43058D8564910",
                   "description": "nora",
                   "graphics":
                   [
                       {
                           "width": 400,
                           "height": 200,
                           "quality": "Low",
                           "url": "https://site/02_201506_011/000C291EE8241ED4AAF43058D8564910Low.jpg"
                       },
                       {
                           "width": 900,
                           "height": 600,
                           "quality": "High",
                           "url": "https://site/02_201506_011/000C291EE8241ED4AAF43058D8564910High.jpg"
                       }
                   ],
                   "endTime": 1423353600000,
                   "activationDate": 1423579699407,
                   "redemption": null
               },
               {
                   "offerId": "000C291EE8241ED4AAF43058D857A910",
                   "description": "nora",
                   "graphics":
                   [
                       {
                           "width": 400,
                           "height": 200,
                           "quality": "Low",
                           "url": "https://site/02_201506_011/000C291EE8241ED4AAF43058D857A910Low.jpg"
                       },
                       {
                           "width": 900,
                           "height": 600,
                           "quality": "High",
                           "url": "https://site/02_201506_011/000C291EE8241ED4AAF43058D857A910High.jpg"
                       }
                   ],
                   "endTime": 1423353600000,
                   "activationDate": 1423579703400,
                   "redemption": null
               },
               {
                   "offerId": "000C291EE8241ED4AAF43058D8608910",
                   "description": "nora",
                   "graphics":
                   [
                       {
                           "width": 400,
                           "height": 200,
                           "quality": "Low",
                           "url": "https://site/02_201506_011/000C291EE8241ED4AAF43058D8608910Low.jpg"
                       },
                       {
                           "width": 900,
                           "height": 600,
                           "quality": "High",
                           "url": "https://site/02_201506_011/000C291EE8241ED4AAF43058D8608910High.jpg"
                       }
                   ],
                   "endTime": 1423353600000,
                   "activationDate": 1423579706707,
                   "redemption": null
               },
               {
                   "offerId": "000C291EE8241ED4AAF43058D862E910",
                   "description": "nora",
                   "graphics":
                   [
                       {
                           "width": 400,
                           "height": 200,
                           "quality": "Low",
                           "url": "https://site/02_201506_011/000C291EE8241ED4AAF43058D862E910Low.jpg"
                       },
                       {
                           "width": 900,
                           "height": 600,
                           "quality": "High",
                           "url": "https://site/02_201506_011/000C291EE8241ED4AAF43058D862E910High.jpg"
                       }
                   ],
                   "endTime": 1423353600000,
                   "activationDate": 1423579710047,
                   "redemption": null
               },
               {
                   "offerId": "000C291EE8241ED4AAF43058D87A0910",
                   "description": "nora",
                   "graphics":
                   [
                       {
                           "width": 400,
                           "height": 200,
                           "quality": "Low",
                           "url": "https://site/02_201506_011/000C291EE8241ED4AAF43058D87A0910Low.jpg"
                       },
                       {
                           "width": 900,
                           "height": 600,
                           "quality": "High",
                           "url": "https://site/02_201506_011/000C291EE8241ED4AAF43058D87A0910High.jpg"
                       }
                   ],
                   "endTime": 1423353600000,
                   "activationDate": 1423579713540,
                   "redemption": null
               },
               {
                   "offerId": "000C291EE8241ED4AAF43058D877E910",
                   "description": "nora",
                   "graphics":
                   [
                       {
                           "width": 400,
                           "height": 200,
                           "quality": "Low",
                           "url": "https://site/02_201506_011/000C291EE8241ED4AAF43058D877E910Low.jpg"
                       },
                       {
                           "width": 900,
                           "height": 600,
                           "quality": "High",
                           "url": "https://site/02_201506_011/000C291EE8241ED4AAF43058D877E910High.jpg"
                       }
                   ],
                   "endTime": 1423353600000,
                   "activationDate": 1423579717533,
                   "redemption": null
               },
               {
                   "offerId": "000C291EE8241ED4AAF43058D87B8910",
                   "description": "nora",
                   "graphics":
                   [
                       {
                           "width": 400,
                           "height": 200,
                           "quality": "Low",
                           "url": "https://site/02_201506_011/000C291EE8241ED4AAF43058D87B8910Low.jpg"
                       },
                       {
                           "width": 900,
                           "height": 600,
                           "quality": "High",
                           "url": "https://site/02_201506_011/000C291EE8241ED4AAF43058D87B8910High.jpg"
                       }
                   ],
                   "endTime": 1423353600000,
                   "activationDate": 1423579721123,
                   "redemption": null
               },
               {
                   "offerId": "000C291EE8241ED4AAF43058D8870910",
                   "description": "nora",
                   "graphics":
                   [
                       {
                           "width": 400,
                           "height": 200,
                           "quality": "Low",
                           "url": "https://site/02_201506_011/000C291EE8241ED4AAF43058D8870910Low.jpg"
                       },
                       {
                           "width": 900,
                           "height": 600,
                           "quality": "High",
                           "url": "https://site/02_201506_011/000C291EE8241ED4AAF43058D8870910High.jpg"
                       }
                   ],
                   "endTime": 1423353600000,
                   "activationDate": 1423579724430,
                   "redemption": null
               },
               {
                   "offerId": "000C297765971EE4A8C22C6999219BA4",
                   "description": "nora",
                   "graphics":
                   [
                       {
                           "width": 400,
                           "height": 200,
                           "quality": "Low",
                           "url": "https://site/02_201504_003/000C297765971EE4A8C22C6999219BA4Low.jpg"
                       },
                       {
                           "width": 900,
                           "height": 600,
                           "quality": "High",
                           "url": "https://site/02_201504_003/000C297765971EE4A8C22C6999219BA4High.jpg"
                       }
                   ],
                   "endTime": 1425168000000,
                   "activationDate": 1423136616203,
                   "redemption": null
               },
               {
                   "offerId": "000C297765971EE4A8C22C699921FBA4",
                   "description": "nora",
                   "graphics":
                   [
                       {
                           "width": 400,
                           "height": 200,
                           "quality": "Low",
                           "url": "https://site/02_201504_003/000C297765971EE4A8C22C699921FBA4Low.jpg"
                       },
                       {
                           "width": 900,
                           "height": 600,
                           "quality": "High",
                           "url": "https://site/02_201504_003/000C297765971EE4A8C22C699921FBA4High.jpg"
                       }
                   ],
                   "endTime": 1425168000000,
                   "activationDate": 1423139501440,
                   "redemption": null
               },
               {
                   "offerId": "000C297765971EE4A8C22C6999233BA4",
                   "description": "nora",
                   "graphics":
                   [
                       {
                           "width": 400,
                           "height": 200,
                           "quality": "Low",
                           "url": "https://site/02_201504_003/000C297765971EE4A8C22C6999233BA4Low.jpg"
                       },
                       {
                           "width": 900,
                           "height": 600,
                           "quality": "High",
                           "url": "https://site/02_201504_003/000C297765971EE4A8C22C6999233BA4High.jpg"
                       }
                   ],
                   "endTime": 1425168000000,
                   "activationDate": 1423215586673,
                   "redemption": null
               }
           ]
       },
       {
           "membershipId": "8315319211",
           "coupons":
           [
               {
                   "offerId": "000C291EE8241ED4AAF43058D85CA910",
                   "description": "nora",
                   "graphics":
                   [
                       {
                           "width": 400,
                           "height": 200,
                           "quality": "Low",
                           "url": "https://site/02_201506_011/000C291EE8241ED4AAF43058D85CA910Low.jpg"
                       },
                       {
                           "width": 900,
                           "height": 600,
                           "quality": "High",
                           "url": "https://site/02_201506_011/000C291EE8241ED4AAF43058D85CA910High.jpg"
                       }
                   ],
                   "endTime": 1423353600000,
                   "activationDate": null,
                   "redemption": null
               },
               {
                   "offerId": "000C291EE8241ED4AAF43058D85F6910",
                   "description": "nora",
                   "graphics":
                   [
                       {
                           "width": 400,
                           "height": 200,
                           "quality": "Low",
                           "url": "https://site/02_201506_011/000C291EE8241ED4AAF43058D85F6910Low.jpg"
                       },
                       {
                           "width": 900,
                           "height": 600,
                           "quality": "High",
                           "url": "https://site/02_201506_011/000C291EE8241ED4AAF43058D85F6910High.jpg"
                       }
                   ],
                   "endTime": 1423353600000,
                   "activationDate": null,
                   "redemption": null
               },
               {
                   "offerId": "000C291EE8241ED4AAF43058D85E2910",
                   "description": "nora",
                   "graphics":
                   [
                       {
                           "width": 400,
                           "height": 200,
                           "quality": "Low",
                           "url": "https://site/02_201506_011/000C291EE8241ED4AAF43058D85E2910Low.jpg"
                       },
                       {
                           "width": 900,
                           "height": 600,
                           "quality": "High",
                           "url": "https://site/02_201506_011/000C291EE8241ED4AAF43058D85E2910High.jpg"
                       }
                   ],
                   "endTime": 1423353600000,
                   "activationDate": null,
                   "redemption": null
               },
               {
                   "offerId": "000C291EE8241ED4AAF43058D85FC910",
                   "description": "nora",
                   "graphics":
                   [
                       {
                           "width": 400,
                           "height": 200,
                           "quality": "Low",
                           "url": "https://site/02_201506_011/000C291EE8241ED4AAF43058D85FC910Low.jpg"
                       },
                       {
                           "width": 900,
                           "height": 600,
                           "quality": "High",
                           "url": "https://site/02_201506_011/000C291EE8241ED4AAF43058D85FC910High.jpg"
                       }
                   ],
                   "endTime": 1423353600000,
                   "activationDate": null,
                   "redemption": null
               },
               {
                   "offerId": "000C291EE8241ED4AAF43058D8776910",
                   "description": "nora",
                   "graphics":
                   [
                       {
                           "width": 400,
                           "height": 200,
                           "quality": "Low",
                           "url": "https://site/02_201506_011/000C291EE8241ED4AAF43058D8776910Low.jpg"
                       },
                       {
                           "width": 900,
                           "height": 600,
                           "quality": "High",
                           "url": "https://site/02_201506_011/000C291EE8241ED4AAF43058D8776910High.jpg"
                       }
                   ],
                   "endTime": 1423353600000,
                   "activationDate": null,
                   "redemption": null
               },
               {
                   "offerId": "000C291EE8241ED4AAF43058D87A8910",
                   "description": "nora",
                   "graphics":
                   [
                       {
                           "width": 400,
                           "height": 200,
                           "quality": "Low",
                           "url": "https://site/02_201506_011/000C291EE8241ED4AAF43058D87A8910Low.jpg"
                       },
                       {
                           "width": 900,
                           "height": 600,
                           "quality": "High",
                           "url": "https://site/02_201506_011/000C291EE8241ED4AAF43058D87A8910High.jpg"
                       }
                   ],
                   "endTime": 1423353600000,
                   "activationDate": null,
                   "redemption": null
               },
               {
                   "offerId": "000C291EE8241ED4AAF43058D87B6910",
                   "description": "nora",
                   "graphics":
                   [
                       {
                           "width": 400,
                           "height": 200,
                           "quality": "Low",
                           "url": "https://site/02_201506_011/000C291EE8241ED4AAF43058D87B6910Low.jpg"
                       },
                       {
                           "width": 900,
                           "height": 600,
                           "quality": "High",
                           "url": "https://site/02_201506_011/000C291EE8241ED4AAF43058D87B6910High.jpg"
                       }
                   ],
                   "endTime": 1423353600000,
                   "activationDate": null,
                   "redemption": null
               },
               {
                   "offerId": "000C291EE8241ED4AAF43058D87D0910",
                   "description": "nora.",
                   "graphics":
                   [
                       {
                           "width": 400,
                           "height": 200,
                           "quality": "Low",
                           "url": "https://site/02_201506_011/000C291EE8241ED4AAF43058D87D0910Low.jpg"
                       },
                       {
                           "width": 900,
                           "height": 600,
                           "quality": "High",
                           "url": "https://site/02_201506_011/000C291EE8241ED4AAF43058D87D0910High.jpg"
                       }
                   ],
                   "endTime": 1423353600000,
                   "activationDate": null,
                   "redemption": null
               }
           ]
       }
   ]
}
```

I have something that works for both memberId's but I want to parameterize so that I pick only the offerId's for a parameter I have in a session that I usually reference like this ${medlem}, I use Scala.

This works:

```
.check(jsonPath("$.membershipCoupons[*].coupons[?(@.activationDate==null)].offerId").findAll.optional.saveAs("itemList"))
```

But how can I say this with a parameter pointing to a specific memberId something like this:

```
     .check(jsonPath("$.membershipCoupons[membershipId[${medlem}]].coupons[?(@.activationDate==null)].offerId").findAll.optional.saveAs("itemList"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to split operation on 2 steps:

```
 arrayMembershipId = $.membershipCoupons[*].membershipId
 n = getIndex(membershipIdArray, yourcode)
 arrayOffer = membershipCoupons[n].coupons[?(@.activationDate==null)].offerId
```